# Already generated AWS signedUrl not working with Android Retrofit2 call for upload videos(mp4)

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, kotlin, amazon-s3, retrofit2

I have a signed url came from AWS.

I use the below code to upload my mp4 file.

```
 val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://www.DUMMEY.com/") // THIS BASE URL AUTOMATICALLY REPLACE ONCE RETROFIT INTERFACE BODY ATTACH WITH @URL
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .build()

        val videoInterface = retrofit.create(
            FileUploadService::class.java
        )

        var apiResponse: Call<Void>
        val requestBody = activity.contentResolver.readAsRequestBody(fileUri)
        apiResponse = videoInterface.upload(
            "video/mp4",
            "Android-OS",
            signedurl,
            requestBody
        )
        apiResponse.enqueue(object : Callback<Void> {
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<Void>,
                response: Response<Void>
            ) {
                Log.d("SUCCESS", "=========API RESPONE SUCCESS=========" + apiResponse)
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<Void>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.e("FAILED", "=========API RESPONE FAILED=========" + apiResponse)
            }

        })
    }.start()



fun ContentResolver.readAsRequestBody(uri: Uri): RequestBody =
    object : RequestBody() {
        override fun contentType(): MediaType? =
            this@readAsRequestBody.getType(uri)?.toMediaTypeOrNull()

        override fun writeTo(sink: BufferedSink) {
            this@readAsRequestBody.openInputStream(uri)?.source()?.use(sink::writeAll)
        }

        override fun contentLength(): Long =
            this@readAsRequestBody.query(uri, null, null, null, null)?.use { cursor ->
                val sizeColumnIndex: Int = cursor.getColumnIndex(SIZE)
                cursor.moveToFirst()
                cursor.getLong(sizeColumnIndex)
            } ?: super.contentLength()
    }

interface FileUploadService {
@PUT
fun upload(
    @Header("Content-Type") contentType: String?,
    @Header("User-Agent") userAgent: String?,
    @Url signingUrl: String?,
    @Body file: RequestBody
): Call<Void>
```

}

But still, I couldn't success with this.

I'm getting "javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Write error: ssl=0xe8abb908: I/O error during system call, Broken pipe" this error all time when running the code. (But I feel this is not only an SSLException, but there is a huge mistake on my code also)

As per the Postman output, it should response "1" with 200 OK.

And I tried with "Multipart.Part" for my file also using this code.

```
   val file = File(fileUri!!.path!!)
   val requestBody = InputStreamRequestBody(activity.contentResolver, fileUri)
   val filePart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", file.name, requestBody)
```

Interface is..

```
 @Multipart
@PUT
fun uploadHope(
    @Header("Content-Type") contentType: String?,
    @Header("User-Agent") userAgent: String?,
    @Url signingUrl: String?,
    @Part file: MultipartBody.Part
): Call<Void>
```

The same error occurred.

I followed this [blog](https://gutier.io/post/android-upload-file-to-aws-s3-bucket-with-retrofit2/) as a help.

Please help me to take "Upload Success" on this.

Answer (score 0):

I did a big investigation but failed. Retrofit2 seems not to support this AWS signedUrl Upload. But I success with the way of 'HttpUrlConnection'. Normally we use.

```
 private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024 * 1024 * 10;



 fun uploadFile(signedurl: String? = null, filePath: String? = null) {
    Thread {
        var serverResponseCode = -1
        try {
            var url: URL? = null
            url = URL(signedurl)
            val connection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
            connection.doOutput = true
            connection.requestMethod = "PUT"
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", " ") // Very important ! It won't work without adding this!
            var dos: DataOutputStream? = null
            var bytesRead: Int
            var bytesAvailable: Int
            var bufferSize: Int
            var buffer: ByteArray
            val sourceFile: File = File(filePath)
            try {
                FileInputStream(sourceFile).use { fileInputStream ->
                    dos = DataOutputStream(connection.outputStream)
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available()
                    bufferSize = Math.min(
                        bytesAvailable,
                        BUFFER_SIZE
                    )
                    buffer = ByteArray(bufferSize)
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize)
                    while (bytesRead > 0) {
                        dos!!.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize)
                        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available()
                        bufferSize = Math.min(
                            bytesAvailable,
                            BUFFER_SIZE
                        )
                        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize)
                    }
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.e("Log", "error " + e)
            } finally {
                // close the streams
                if (dos != null) {
                    dos!!.flush() //send any left data
                    dos!!.close()
                }
            }
            serverResponseCode = connection.responseCode
            Log.e("response", "response code " + serverResponseCode)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.e("Log", "error " + e)
        }
    }.start()
}
```

If you follow this method please highlight these lines,

```
var url: URL? = null
            url = URL(signedurl)
            val connection = url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection


connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", " ") // Very important ! It won't work without adding this!
```

Note:- In some condition, this service may **respond 200 (Ok), but content might not be uploaded**. Because AWS S3 bucket just takes file object it doesn't check content available or nor just reply 200. so if this error happens, contact the server and see what is the error first.

If someone finds a way to upload via retrofit2 to AWS . please answer here.

Comment: I am facing the same issue with Retrofit and tried your code too. getting 200 but image file not uploaded

Comment: You can follow the same steps I 've done here, and then contact your back-end developer who takes your uploaded image, and check what happens in the DB backend side